# How to link a Django model field to an instance of the same model

Tags: django, key, models

I'm trying to design a Django model for articles with attributes like title, publication date, etc. One of the attributes is other article(s) that the article in question is commenting on. I'm not sure how to code this since there is no foreign key involved - I just want a reference to other instances of the Article model (i.e. one or more other articles). This is what I have so far:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    publication_date = date_published = models.DateField()
    comment_on = ?????????????
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you should user ForeignKey

```
 comment_on = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
```

> To create a recursive relationship -- an object that has a many-to-one
>   relationship with itself -- use  models.ForeignKey('self').

[Django foreign key docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I will now go learn about recursive relationships....Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, it seems that this code only allows me to link to one article. But sometimes an article comments on two or more articles. I tried to create additional fields using the same code (i.e. comment_on1, comment_on2, etc), but Django wouldn't permit this. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use **ManyToManyField**

```
comment_on = models.ManyToManyField('self',null=True,blank=True)
```

refer to [DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) for further symmetric use.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will do that.